# Outdoor Ac unit causes home cinema to hum

Tags: noise-reduction, air

The design of my new home placed the outdoor ac unit of my ducted system right outside my home theatre.

I love my new house but this is really bothering me as it makes the home theatre feel like an airplane cabin sometimes. The low frequency vibration causes the room to hum.

The unit has been inspected multiple times by the installer and by the vendor (Actron air). No issue has been found. No obstruction or cause of extra vibration has been found. The internal plaster has been removed to ensure no obstruction or saddle is causing it.

The compressor is directly outside the room and the pipes come through the wall next to the seating area. There is a decent sized hole in the outside wall (Hebel) where the pipe comes in which has been sealed.

I would love some advice on how I can make it better. Or if any of these options are better than the others.

I have considered:

1. Relocating the outdoor unit to the other side of the house. But expecting this to be expensive as pipes will need to be relocated.
2. Building a box around the unit to seal off some of the noise. Difficult as the unit is close to the wall.
3. Opening up the seal in the wall and filling with expanding foam. Not sure how much noise this will stop, and whether it’s ok to put expanding foam next to these pipes.
4. Rotating the outdoor unit to put the compressor on the other side, slightly further from the theatre
5. Relocating the pipes so that they go up the outside of the wall rather than inside the wall.

Other info:

- The home theatre has sounds-stop plaster.
- Cooling is louder than heating[image]

Comment: What you are hearing, might be caused by vibrations more than by sound.  Would try to isolate the outdoor AC unit from the cement pad and/or wall it is sitting on first.  My knowledge not good enough, but a rubber pad/s might help, or ACME sky hooks.

Comment: The unit may be defective.  If the motor is imbalanced either because of a manufacturing mistake or damage in shipping, you should get it replaced.  You'll have to prove that the vibrations are abnormal, for which you should bring as many experienced people as you can.  I had a similar problem and it was only after the 5th service call to the installer when they sent a new technician who immediately took my side and made them replace it under warranty.

Comment: Check the possibility the noise is being conducted through the cement. You may be able to put vibration isolation dampers under the Condenser.

Comment: sadly, none of those will help low frequency noise very much. Do something to separate the concrete pad from the house and/or the unit from the pad to stop the unabated transmission. Inside the room, stiffen the walls and isolate material interfaces. Ex. sections of rubber band or poster putty tucked between HVAC vent and ceiling drywall. Poster putty everywhere really; switch/plate covers. Make walls heavier. Wave have to accelerate the medium and how much they do that determines amplitude (volume here), so more mass = lower amplitude. Heavy mirrors or paintings, tapestries, etc will help.